# ERROR SpringApplication IllegalAccessError tried to access method org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrySupport.getDefaultEditor

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have been trying deploy SpringBoot project on tomcat server, In local run maven success

[image]

But, I have been trying export .war file and deploy on tomcat get error.

> ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
>   20:10:54.170 [http-nio-8080-exec-13] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrySupport.getDefaultEditor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/beans/PropertyEditor; from class org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$TypeConverterConverter
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$TypeConverterConverter.getPropertyEditor(BindConverter.java:239)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$TypeConverterConverter.matches(BindConverter.java:224)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConvertersForPair.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:669)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.getRegisteredConverter(GenericConversionService.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.find(GenericConversionService.java:550)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.canConvert(GenericConversionService.java:145)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$TypeConverterConversionService.canConvert(BindConverter.java:201)
>       at org.springframework.boot.convert.DelimitedStringToArrayConverter.matches(DelimitedStringToArrayConverter.java:51)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConvertersForPair.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:669)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.getRegisteredConverter(GenericConversionService.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.find(GenericConversionService.java:550)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:260)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.canConvert(GenericConversionService.java:145)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$TypeConverterConversionService.canConvert(BindConverter.java:201)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$CompositeConversionService.convert(BindConverter.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.convert(IndexedElementsBinder.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.bindValue(IndexedElementsBinder.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.bindIndexed(IndexedElementsBinder.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.bindIndexed(IndexedElementsBinder.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ArrayBinder.bindAggregate(ArrayBinder.java:46)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateBinder.bind(AggregateBinder.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindAggregate$3(Binder.java:388)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$200(Binder.java:486)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindAggregate(Binder.java:388)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:349)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:281)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.getProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:604)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$asDocuments$11(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:577)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>       at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4717)
>       at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4725)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>       at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>       at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.asDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:578)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:563)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:518)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:494)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:464)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443)
>       at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$8(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:443)
>       at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:440)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$0(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:335)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.FilteredPropertySource.apply(FilteredPropertySource.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:323)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:176)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1309)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:665)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:211)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:595)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

This is pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<groupId>xxx.xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thailife</groupId>
        <artifactId>queueman</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/queueman.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What Tomcat version do you use?

Comment: Tomcat version 8.5.23